# Raspberry Pi hangs after boot

Tags: boot, firmware

I have two Raspberry Pi's. One will boot up into [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian) just fine. If I take the same SD card, network connection, keyboard and mouse and use it with the other Raspberry Pi, it boots and then hangs when it gets to the login screen.

The keyboard does not work, and I can't SSH in to it (it has a fixed IP address, so I know it's the correct IP address).

SSH and the keyboard work with the same SD card in the other Raspberry Pi.

I've tried another SD card with an earlier version of [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) for Raspberry Pi on it and the same results as above happen, so it's not the SD card or Linux distribution causing the crash.

May a firmware update help? But how do I get it booted so the firmware can be updated?

Comment: Does the both of the SD Cards contain the same image?

Comment: The firmware is installed on the SD card, so you can update it on the working Raspberry Pi and then test it in the one that is not working. However, I think this may be a return job. You should also try a powered USB hub, just to be certain.

Comment: @Haskeller no, they differ. Different cards and different versions of linux.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I did a firmware update on the working rPi then used the same SD card to boot the second rPi and it still hangs. I agree, it's looking like a return job.

Comment: Can you post the boot logs?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. no logs. it hangs before I can do anything with it. It does do SSH for about 10 seconds, then hang. The power is a 5VDC 850mA. With HDMI connected I see it booting until it shows the config blue screen. Then all disappears and only power led is on.

Comment: Could you give us the log files? Just pull `/var/log/` from the SD card, zip them, upload the zip file, and provide a link.

Answer (score 2):

Check power to be sufficient. Measure voltage between TP1 and TP2. It should be 4.75 V or higher. Otherwise many upredictably things could happen. May be even this one.

Comment: I don't have a voltmeter to check the power level. The other raspberry pi works fine with the supply. The PSU I am using is the one from RS Components that they sell for use with the raspberry PI - it can be found here; [USB PSU 5V 1.2A - RS Components](http://raspberrypi.rsdelivers.com/product/rs/hnp06-microusb/micro-usb-uk-power-supply-for-raspberry-pi/7263069.aspx)